# Java JmenuItem do something when clicked not working

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel

I am currently trying to make a GUI with a menu that has 2 options you can select from. One being "Default Settings" and one being "Custom Settings." When you click on either one, it will take you to the new jPanel that will display the proper windows, text boxes, etc for that panel. However, I cannot seem to get the mouseClicked action to actually switch between the panels. As a test, I have a simple jLabel on each panel that says "Default" for the default panel and "custom" for the custom panel, and each menu item, when clicked respectively, should switch between them. Here is my current code:

```
frmLegitServerAdder = new JFrame();
frmLegitServerAdder.setTitle("Legit Server Adder 5 Million");
frmLegitServerAdder.setBounds(100, 100, 546, 468);
frmLegitServerAdder.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
frmLegitServerAdder.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

JMenu mnNewMenu = new JMenu("Settings");
menuBar.add(mnNewMenu);

JMenuItem menuItemDefaultSettings = new JMenuItem("Default Settings");
mnNewMenu.add(menuItemDefaultSettings);

JMenuItem menuItemCustomSettings = new JMenuItem("Custom Logon Settings");
mnNewMenu.add(menuItemCustomSettings);


frmLegitServerAdder.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

final JPanel defaultSettingsPanel = new JPanel();
frmLegitServerAdder.getContentPane().add(defaultSettingsPanel, "name_416522810155567");
defaultSettingsPanel.setLayout(null);

JLabel lblDefaultArea = new JLabel("Default Area");
lblDefaultArea.setBounds(217, 11, 90, 14);
defaultSettingsPanel.add(lblDefaultArea);

final JPanel customSettingsPanel = new JPanel();
frmLegitServerAdder.getContentPane().add(customSettingsPanel, "name_416549691176064");
customSettingsPanel.setLayout(null);

JLabel lblCustomArea = new JLabel("Custom Area");
lblCustomArea.setBounds(235, 21, 46, 14);
customSettingsPanel.add(lblCustomArea);

menuItemDefaultSettings.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        defaultSettingsPanel.setVisible(true);
        customSettingsPanel.setVisible(false);

    }
});

menuItemCustomSettings.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        defaultSettingsPanel.setVisible(false);
        customSettingsPanel.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

The code runs and the GUI displays just fine, but nothing actually happens when I click on either menu items, as it should. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should NOT be using a MouseListener. Instead you should be adding an ActionListener to the menu item. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more information.
2. You should be using a CardLayout when you want to swap components. See [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) from the same tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need `ActionListener`

```
menuItemDefaultSettings.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        defaultSettingsPanel.setVisible(true);
        customSettingsPanel.setVisible(false);

    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Is it advisable to always just use ActionListeners instead of specific listeners in your code?

Comment: It depends on your use case.